# program crashing

Tags: c, arrays

For homework I have to write a code that reads in a persons "ID" and adds their vote to one of four choices. I have what i think is the code written out but whenever I run it in codeblocks it crashes and i'm not sure why.
This is what I've written:

```
   #include<stdio.h>

int main (){

    //create array for IDs to see if number was repeated?
   int number;
   int ID[number];

   //start counts for each voting option
   int Acount=0;
   int Bcount=0;
   int Ccount=0;
   int Dcount=0;
   char choice;

    while(number != -1){
        printf("What is your ID?\n");
        //read in size of array
        int i;

        for (i=0; i<number; i++){
        scanf("%d",&number);
        for (i=0;i<number;i++){
            ID[number]=1;
            printf("You have already voted. You cannot vote again.");
            continue;
        //make array to look for repeating IDs?
        //scan that array to see if number is repeated
        continue;
        }

        printf("Welcome %d, which vote would you like to place?\n", number);
        //if valid char is said add +1 to char count
        scanf("%c", &choice);
            if(choice == 'A'){
                Acount + 1;
                printf("You have successfully voted for A.\n");
            }
            else if(choice == 'B'){
                Bcount + 1;
                printf("You have successfully voted for B.\n");
            }
            else if(choice == 'C'){
                Ccount + 1;
                printf("You have successfully voted for C.\n");
            }
            else if(choice == 'D'){
                Dcount + 1;
                printf("You have successfully voted for D.\n");
            }
            continue;
        }

    }

    // -1 must have been entered so
    //print winner and end program
    if(Acount>Bcount && Acount>Ccount && Acount>Dcount){
        printf("A wins with %d votes!\n", Acount);
    }
    else if(Bcount>Acount && Bcount>Ccount && Bcount>Dcount){
        printf("B wins with %d votes!\n", Bcount);
    }
    else if(Ccount>Acount && Ccount>Bcount && Ccount>Dcount){
        printf("C wins with %d votes!\n", Ccount);
    }
    else if(Dcount>Acount && Dcount>Bcount && Dcount>Ccount){
        printf("D wins with %d votes!\n", Dcount);
    }
 return 0;

}
```

Comment: `number` isn't initialized when you create an array of variable(`number`) length which leads to the crash. To fix it, move `int ID[number];` just after the first `scanf`. BTW, your code has other problems which I hope you will fix.

Answer (score 0):

number is not defined. You have two ways. Define a macro :

```
#define NUMBER 20 /* using capitals is better */
int ID[NUMBER];
```

Or get the number from stdin :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int number;
scanf("%d",&number);
```